# Is WebRTC available in Chrome 21 for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, webrtc

I'm trying to find any information if `GetUserMedia` is enabled on Chrome 21 running on iPad or iPhone without success.

I know that `peerConnection` is still available only on Chrome Canary or in regular Chrome but with flag switched. As far as I know you can't access `about:flags` on iOS. Is there currently any way to get WebRTC in Chrome on iOS running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize that this is an old question but new info has been pushed out in the last 2 years with respect to WebRTC and iOS.

From all that I have read, Google is [slowly moving towards making WebRTC available in Chrome for iOS](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/bch_feIJn88). However, there are still [many bugs that they are working out](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=3566) and it is still in the very early stages even in Chrome 32.

But in short, [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/B2f4vLaoXJI) shows the pains with enabling it and why Chrome 21 does/did not have it.

Additional resources:

- [More recent SO question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811361/using-getusermedia-stream-api-with-ios-6)
- [Some other issues with Browsers on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23391401/1818849)