# Using getUserMedia/Stream API with iOS 6

Tags: html, ios6

I am trying to build a web app that will allow users to use the built in camera on an iPad to take a picture or video of themselves and then post it to Facebook. So far I have had no luck when testing `getUserMedia()` in Safari for iOS 6 or the Chrome app.

This info graphic shows that it is not supported by Safari with iOS 6 but it should work with Chrome, no?

http://caniuse.com/stream

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Currently the only way for mobile Safari to get an image from the camera (or photo roll) is with an input element. It is quite simple:

```
<input id="image-picker" type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

Then in js:

```
$("#image-picker").change( function (event) {
  var files = event.target.files;
  if (files.length>0) {
    // Do something with files[0]
  }
});
```

Comment: This only works in iOS 6, any version of iOS previous to that doesn't support file uploads at all

Answer (score 0):

Chrome for iOS uses identical methods/views for displaying and interpreting HTML, with the exception of a few Safari-specific optimizations.  If Safari does not support `getUserMedia()`, then Chrome cannot support it either unless they build their own port of WebKit for iOS, and even then, it might be a stretch.  The functionality you are after may be available through some other means, but not using `getUserMedia()`.

Comment: I thought the point of Chrome limited is because Apple/AppStore won't allow browsers to implement their own renderers?

Comment: What I said may not actually be true however. It seems Ericsson provide an iOS browser called Bowser which is WebRTC enabled: https://labs.ericsson.com/apps/bowser

Comment: @DanH unfortunately bowser is no longer available: http://labs.ericsson.com/blog/retiring-bowser. Is there an iOS browser which has getUserMedia available?

Comment: Bowser is back on the App Store, I can view the camera using getUserMedia (Hurray!), but I'm having trouble capturing images https://itunes.apple.com/app/bowser/id560478358?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Now Safari supports it starting from IOS 11 & Safari 11.
The namespaces have changed a little as its now mediaDevices prefixed.
Check https://caniuse.com/?search=mediaDevices