# Augmented Reality ( AR ) on HTML5 and WebGL

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, augmented-reality

I have a web app that is about to get released and i will make an Hybrid App from the web source and i want to add the AR feature to the mobile application, i saw working examples online combining HTML5 video elements and WebGL technology, but what made me curious is that not all mobile OS versions in Android and iOS are supporting the HTML based Augmented Reality.

Is it possible to link HTML Mobile App to native resources to get a more supported AR feature? give me just the name of available technologies to do this, i will follow and search till i get it functioning.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, the problem with cross-browser AR is that iOS [does not support getUserMedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160819/how-to-use-getusermedia-in-chrome-for-ios) (part of webRTC) for getting a feed from the device camera which is essential for an AR application.

I didn't try it, but I believe that using [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) along with one of these plugins, you should be able to get a camera feed to process for AR:
- https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc
- https://github.com/daraosn/Cordova-CanvasCamera
- https://github.com/donaldp24/CanvasCameraPlugin

Hope this gets you in the right direction...