# GetUserMedia iOS issue?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the following code in an HTML5 page. When I run my page on Android and PC (chrome), the code works fine and I get the correct JavaScript `alert();` but when I run the same page on an iOS device like iPhone or iPad, I don't get anything (no `alert()` at all).

This is my code:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia || // use the proper vendor prefix
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);

navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, function() {
   alert('camera is supported in your browser');
}, function() {
   alert('camera is not supported in your browser!');
});
```

Is there something that I'm missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `getUserMedia` is part of WebRTC and isn't supported by Safari/Apple at this point in time. See: http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/ And see this question for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374806/webapp-using-webrtc-for-cross-platform-videochat-in-ios-browser-and-android-chro/23391401#23391401

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebApp using webRTC for cross-platform videochat in iOS Browser and Android Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374806/webapp-using-webrtc-for-cross-platform-videochat-in-ios-browser-and-android-chro)

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score -1):

It will work in fall 2017, once **iOS11** is released.

Comment: Could you show an article or source where you found this?

Comment: @wildpeaks https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/92713