# Add webRTC in webview in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I have created a chat but with webView. The problem is the chat has video and voice that is not supported with iOS because it does not support webRTC.

The main question is how can I easily add RTC inside webView in Swift to support iOS video and voice?

Comment: SFSafariViewController now supports webrtc in ios13. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183201#c28

Comment: should probably update the accepted question to the 2nd answer, which is more updated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebApp using webRTC for cross-platform videochat in iOS Browser and Android Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374806/webapp-using-webrtc-for-cross-platform-videochat-in-ios-browser-and-android-chro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately with the current WebRTC support in the iOS web browser, you can't easily add WebRTC. You would have to use the native iOS libraries (https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/).

Comment: I think this has changed. iOS 11 has WebRTC support in it's WKWebView :)

Comment: it's not WKWebView still doesn't support WebRTC

Comment: It has *some* supoort. checkout my answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49467964/1047547

Comment: @zaxy78 any news with iOS 12 ? for getUserMedia

Comment: @Luis, I noticed someone found a WebKit JS call to re-activate the getUserMedia. want to try to reproduce and let us know if it really works?
See the comment on this page: http://www.openradar.me/33571214

Comment: @zaxy78 it doesn't work the comment says "However, the call getUserMedia fails with the error "SecurityError: The operation is insecure.". I did not manage yet to work around it.",  there is an internal ticket open on apple with id 29281220 , to resolve this issue ( there is no way to see the link to the ticket )

Comment: disappointing :( but thanks for the update. will update if I notice a change

Comment: will something change for iOS 13 ?

Comment: Now, WKWebView on iOS 14.3 supports WebRTC

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek yap, notice my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

### From iOS 14.3 (Beta)

Apple is adding full support to WebRTC in WKWebView !

Learn more here: https://webkit.org/blog/11353/mediarecorder-api/

### From iOS11+

Apple has added support for **WebRTC** to *Safari*.

If you want to use *WKWebView* - there is only a partial support.
Checkout this answer:

[WebRTC Support in iOS 11 - Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49467964/1047547)

Comment: WKWebView still doesn't support WebRTC even Safari does

Comment: It does support *some* of its features, but not getUserMedia().
checkout my full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49467964/1047547

Answer (score 2):

**getUserMedia not supported in WKWebView**

This bug was filed in radar, which is Apple's bug tracking system : http://www.openradar.me/33571214

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: Unfortunately, there is **only microphone support** in this framework!

---

Finally, there is a solution!

**WKWebViewRTC** is a brand new WebRTC library for WKWebView for Swift on iOS, and it works like a charm!

https://github.com/OpenTelecom/WKWebViewRTC

1. clone repository and build framework
2. add framework to your project with "Embed & Sign" setting
3. add this line of code after WKWebView initialization

   ```
    WKWebViewRTC(wkwebview: webView, contentController: controller)
   ```

This way mediaDevices and getUsermedia are available to use.

Minimum iOS version of framework is iOS 12.