# Does webKit in iOS 11 (Beta) support WebRTC?

Tags: ios, safari, webkit, webrtc, wkwebview

I have a URL that is working fine with Safari on iOS11 (Beta) Audio/Video is working fine. 
But when I load this URL with  WKWebView it gives me an error "Incompatible Browser" and when I check my browser version in WebKit it shows "WebKit based browser on iOS 11"

So the question really is, has Apple included this change in the WKWebview webkit (which should be the same as Safari) for the developer BETA of iOS 11?

Comment: I see the same symptom using the tokbox web sdk. Initial feedback from tokbox is to "not expect" support of webrtc in WKWebview. I've asked for definitive confirmation (ideally from Apple).

Comment: @steve1951 did you ever get any official word on WebRTC support in a WebView?

Comment: nothing official, but upon more attentive reading Apple seems to go out of their way to state webrtc is available in Safari with no mention of WKWebview.

Comment: I answered Yes - It's supported - since it is more updated information.
Consider selecting new Answer for this one?

Answer (score 39):

#### Update: WebRTC Support is coming in iOS14.3 (Beta)

Learn more here: https://webkit.org/blog/11353/mediarecorder-api/

#### From iOS11+ :

WebRTC is **partially supported** in *WKWebView*, 
 and **fully supported**  in the *Safari App* browser.

---

**Explained:**

WebRTC has three main JavaScript APIs:

- MediaStream (aka getUserMedia)
- RTCPeerConnection
- RTCDataChannel

For apps running inside **Safari App,** iOS11+, all WebRTC APIs are supported. That includes `getUserMedia`. Be sure to use *adapter.js* library for best compatibility, since each browser - including Safari - uses a different name for its implementation. For example, in Safari it's `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`.

But, when using **WKWebView** or **SFSafariViewController**, it's a different story:

- Both `RTCPeerConnection` and `RTCDataChannel` **are** supported and working.
- `getUserMedia` is [**not** supported yet](http://www.openradar.me/33571214), for "security reasons". It most probably [won't be available before the next major OS release](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88052#thread-message-278803), which would be iOS 12 in September 2018.

You can still stream video & audio from local storage or consume live media captured by a peer. Hopefully in iOS 12 we'll see some progress...

Comment: Got any citations for this?

Comment: Works on both iPhone & iPads. source: https://webkit.org/blog/7726/announcing-webrtc-and-media-capture/

Comment: I was hoping for more on the "getUserMedia" not supported. I'm trying to get webRTC to work in safari on iphone. Currently it's intermittent at best.

Comment: It's for security reasons. it takes the Apple team approx. ~1 year to fully support new features from WebKit inside the WKWebView...
it was released on June'17 so stay tuned...

Comment: I meant Native safari, not the webview inside apps. Does your statement still hold true for the safari ios browser?

Comment: I understand now, see me updated answer. (yes it works; but use adapter.js from https://github.com/webrtc/adapter)

Comment: I've been using WebRTC in production in a WkWebView for a while now - it works (RTCDataChannel). tvOS is baffling though - no way to use WebRTC there without bringing your own libwebrtc.

Comment: The issue is listed on Open Radar, the (unofficial) Apple issue tracker. http://www.openradar.me/33571214 "getUserMedia not supported in WKWebView"

Comment: getUserMedia not being available in WKWebView is also the reason why other browsers such as Chrome won't have access to the camera e.g. for video chat solutions. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=752458

Comment: The topic was discussed on the Apple Developer Forums and most probably, WKWebView won't provide support for getUserMedia until the next "major OS release", i.e. not before iOS 12 around September 2018. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88052#thread-post-278803

Comment: seems like there might be a workaround to enabled getUserMedia() using WebKit APIs. see this comment on OpenRedar: http://www.openradar.me/33571214

Comment: iOS 12 is now out, and it appears that getUserMedia is still not supported in WKWebView.  In Chrome 70 for iOS (which uses WKWebView), navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia is undefined.

Comment: Is there any way to pass the RTCMediaStream from native code to wkwebview?

Comment: @WorieN have you tried using WebRTC itself to send it to itself on 127.0.0.1, you don't even need a signaling server?

Comment: @zaxy78 can u please update the answer about the status in iOS 12 and 13?

Comment: Still no getUserMedia support as of iOS 13.2

Comment: iOS 14.3 started supporting `getUserMedia()`

Answer (score 9):

I did a bit of digging in the WebKit sources last night, and it looks like the WebRTC/MediaCapture stuff is all gated behind a preference that's only accessible via a private API.  There was also a commit that mentioned something about apps needing to handle all the setup for A/V permissions.

In any case, the result is that getUserMedia doesn't work in WKWebView, even on iOS11 (beta 4, at least) :(

I've filed a radar (rdar://33571214 and http://www.openradar.me/33571214) and encourage everyone else to do the same.

Comment: I managed to access the private API and accept camera permission request by following this test https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/5e250ba19a76ccf164d1d31e6a49700bab34826e/Tools/TestWebKitAPI/Tests/WebKitCocoa/UserMediaDisabled.mm . I can run the mock media capture but i still can't get a live camera capture, i get this error "Could not create a 'com.apple.webkit.camera' sandbox extension". Do you have any idea how to get pass this error?

Comment: Did you succeed? I'm also looking to activate sound and video in my project via getUserMedia. How can I access the Private API? My project is in swift

Answer (score 3):

I have done some tests with iOS Beta 4 and it seems that even WKWebview nor UIWebview don't support getUserMedia as a WebRTC API.

Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Yes, the WKWebView/UIWebView does not suppor the use of getUserMedia.

Comment: we experience the same, does not seem to work with in-app safari

Comment: only since 14.3 beta. see my answer above (updated)