# WebKit + WebRTC without Safari 11/Safari Preview and High Sierra

Tags: ios, macos, webkit, webrtc, hardware

I'm really intrigued with WebRTC and want to start building web based technologies that have access to hardware and other aspects of what a native application might have. My question is, how might I implement WebRTC into WebKit, without using High Sierra for macOS or Safari 11/Safari Preview? This goes beyond using Chrome or Firefox to test some WebRTC components. I want to be able to implement an instance of WebKit, maybe using webview in a macOS app, and include WebRTC.

Maybe even, a framework that I could use in Xcode and Swift for a macOS app or iOS app? That would be even more awesome!

What I've looked at so far:

https://webkit.org/blog/7763/a-closer-look-into-webrtc/

http://www.webrtcinwebkit.org

https://www.openwebrtc.org

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/

https://www.openwebrtc.org/bowser/

Also found this to be interesting:

http://thejackalofjavascript.com/node-webkit-webrtc-and-angularjs-a-video-chat-client/

Comment: Another link: WebRTC Native Code https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/ - it's a chunk of the Google Chrome browser. C++, bare minimum: establishing connections and pushing raw audio/video buffers (just like good old VoIP and video conferencing libraries).

Comment: you can use WebRTC inside a WKWebView since iOS 11 . checkout my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49467964/1047547

Note: no getUserMedia() API thought, only the others...