# Safari WebRTC support in IOS 11

Tags: ios, webrtc, ios11

We have an application developed using `WebRTC` in `iOS 11`, and it says it supports `WebRTC` but the application is not working in `Safari` on `iOS 11`. Is there anything required to do from our end to support this on the `Safari` browser? Do we have to make any changes in the script? Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055329/does-webkit-in-ios-11-beta-support-webrtc and https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-ios-support/

Answer (score 0):

Did you got the last adapter.js that assume the browser compatibility ?

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that worked for me

```
// create video element first 
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.style.width = document.width + 'px';
video.style.height = document.height + 'px';
video.setAttribute('autoplay', '');
video.setAttribute('muted', '');
video.setAttribute('playsinline', '');
document.body.appendChild(video);

 //setup your constraints 
  constraints = {
     audio: false,
     video: {
       facingMode: front
      }
   }

  //ask navigator to allow access 
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function 
 success(stream) {
   video.srcObject = stream; 
 });
});
```