# Xamarin: Enable microphone from webview for iOS device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin.Forms.WebView to display a website in my Xamarin application. The rendered website requires the user to record audio using microphone. The recording works fine when I open the website in safari browser on iPhone and iPad but doesn't work when opened from WebView. I also noticed that when I open the website in browser it asks permission to access microphone but that doesn't happen in WebView.

Comment: Did you add the microphone usage key in your info.plist file `<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>`?

Comment: Yes I have added the key in info.plist

Answer (score 1):

Try to [Request Authorization for Media Capture on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios?language=objc) before your start recording:

```
        AVCaptureDevice.RequestAccessForMediaType(AVMediaType.Audio, (bool isAccessGranted) => {
            //if has access              
            if (isAccessGranted)
            {
                //do something
            }
            //if has no access
            else
            {
                //show an alert
            }
        });
```

> Recording audio or video always requires explicit permission from the user

Refer: [requestaccessformediatype](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624584-requestaccessformediatype?language=objc)

Comment: Thanks Jack, I'm able to get permissions to enable microphone, but the audio recording is still not working on the webview. Any idea what thew problem might be.

Comment: It seems a limitation in iOS app. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055329/does-webkit-in-ios-11-beta-support-webrtc/49467964#49467964) and [here](https://github.com/zxing-js/library/issues/15#issuecomment-381572333).