# Enable WebRTC Support in WKWebView/UIWebView

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, wkwebview

I am developing a flutter application using WebRTC in [webview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview). On android, it is working as expected, but facing issues on iOS build. I have read the threads [Apple Support](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/88052?page=3) and [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055329/does-webkit-in-ios-11-beta-support-webrtc/49467964#49467964).

Both threads state, WebRTC is not allowed inside iOS webview. I tested my code in emulator/real-device, but unsuccessful.

So, my question is anybody know how can I run the WebRTC in iOS webview?

This is how I am showing the webview

```
InAppWebView(
                initialUrl: widget.callType == AppConstant.INCOMING ? incomingUrl : outGoingUrl,
                initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                  crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                      mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
                      debuggingEnabled: true,
                      clearCache: true,
                      javaScriptEnabled: true,
                      preferredContentMode: UserPreferredContentMode.MOBILE
                  ),
                ),
                onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                  //web view created
                },
                androidOnPermissionRequest: (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin, List<String> resources) async {
                  print('resource list : ${resources.toString()}');
                  return PermissionRequestResponse(resources: resources, action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
                }
            );
```

Comment: Your issue is already on open in Inappwebview git project.you can track this,https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/200

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ios Webview and WKWebView hasn't had WebRTC support until now.

From ios 14.3 ios is offering support for WKWebView:
https://leemartin.medium.com/ios-14-3-brings-webrtc-to-wkwebview-closing-gap-on-ios-accessibility-90a83fa6bda2

You need to update your iOS in your phone and/or Xcode 12.3.

Additionally, depending on your webview plugin ( in my case I am using cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) could be necessary to modify it to add permissions for video, camera, and VoIP.

Comment: I am managing the device with iOS 14.3. I am using flutter development, so can not try Cordova plugin at first place. And please add a reference/example code of using cordova.

Comment: iOS 14.3 has enabled the webrtc access. and it is working. future reader can check the functionality from listed samples https://webrtc.github.io/samples/ by running them in iOS safari browser.

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan did you manage to run your app on iOS device(iOS 14.3 and/or above)?

Comment: I was surprised to see that WebRTC works well on IOS using Chrome and Firefox as well as on IpadOS (Chrome/Firefox). Is that compatibility due to IOS 14.3 too ? Because I don't see any announcement yet as well as no WebRTC compatibility table update